# Running a terminal command inside an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, terminal, command, cydia

Hey guys.
So, I'm trying to have my iPhone app (jailbreaked) run a terminal command, and show the output. For those who don't see what I mean, I want to do the same thing as Cydia does when installing a package (black screen with the command output)

I'm using xCode 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Cydia is not directly running external programs: it is linked against libapt-inst, which indirectly runs dpkg to generate some (but not all) of that output.

In general, you just want to render a black text box with some white text, and then use `popen` to run your external program, `fread`ing any data from the pipe into your app to add to the end of the box.